# Visual studio code automatically replaces @this with < blade this >

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-livewire

I am using a Laravel-Livewire stack.

I do not know why, but every time I save the document, Visual Studio Code replaces `@this` with `< blade this >`.

Can someone help me to avoid that?

Before saving the file "favorite.blade.php,".

```php
<div> something </div>
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
            $('.select2').select2();
            $('.select2').on('change', function(e) {
                var data = $('.select2').select2("val");
                @this
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

After saving the file **favorite.blade.php**.

```php
<div> something </div>
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
            $('.select2').select2();
            $('.select2').on('change', function(e) {
                var data = $('.select2').select2("val"); <
                blade this >
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

My vs-code setting.JSON contains this setting.

```js
"[php]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    }
```

Comment: maybe u are running an extension that does that..

Comment: Try disabling `formatOnSave`. Maybe formatter does that.

Comment: Are you running a Blade specific extension? For a start, disable all extensions and enable them one by one to check which one could cause this. (What exactly does `@this` do in JS?)

Comment: I follow your suggestion. The extension that is generating the problem is called "Beautify Blade". I do not why it is replacing. It was the first time that something like that happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is caused by the [`apility.beautify-blade`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=apility.beautify-blade) extension. Since you're not doing blade development in this workspace, you can disable the extension just for that workspace, or disable it globally and just enable it in the workspaces where you need it.

Note that you can find out what extension (if any) is causing a certain behaviour by doing the following: Reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette). If it still happens, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.